# How to disable pie-menu for Ctrl + S

Tags: saving, pie-menu

How do I disable the Pie menu for Ctrl S?
I didn't have it before, I don't know what I messed with, and now it shows up.
it shows Saving, Open, Append.

Just the pie menu for saving, how do I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Addons</kbd> and search for <kbd>pie</kbd>. Scroll down the list of entries in the <kbd>Interface: 3D Viewport Pie Menus</kbd> and uncheck the <kbd>Save Open Pie: Hotkey: 'Ctrl S'</kbd> entry. If you don't have autosave preferences checked on the bottom-left menu, click <kbd>Save</kbd><kbd>Preferences</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I am grateful, Mr. John. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!